# Strange shared_ptr comparator selection for priority queue in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl, clang

I have a class wrapped in `std::shared_ptr`, and I want to select top-k objects with help of `std::priority_queue`. So, I define `operator <` and expect that everything will be fine. But it is not true. By default (with gcc) `std::priority_queue` use default comparator for `std::shared_ptr`, which compares addresses.

But behaviour is different if I use std::sort for std::vector with no comparator specified my `operator <` will be used. It is little bit unexpected and inconsistent behaviour.

Code sample:

```
struct document
{   
    float rank;
    document(float rank):
        rank(rank)
    { }
};

using doc_ptr = shared_ptr<document>;

bool operator < (const doc_ptr& x, const doc_ptr& y)
{   
    return x->rank < y->rank;
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<doc_ptr> pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        float r = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        pq.push(make_shared<document>(r));
    }

    vector<doc_ptr> pq_v;

    while(!pq.empty()) {
        cout << pq.top()->rank << " " << uint64_t(pq.top().get()) << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get following output:

```
0.277775 35463848
0.76823 35463800
0.335223 35463752
0.197551 35463704
0.55397 35463560
0.911647 35463512
0.783099 35463384
0.79844 35463336
0.394383 35463288
0.840188 35463208
```

With clang (Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)) everything works like expected.

Full code with `std::priority_queue` and `std::sort` for `std::vector`: https://ideone.com/awsdrO

I guess it is can be something about name resolution, but I can't find it out by myself. So, I wonder who is right here and why?

**UPD**: Much simpler example here: https://ideone.com/wm1YBw
Last line of output differs in gcc and clang, because gcc provides specialization of `std::less` for `shared_ptr`, but clang doesn't.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but to print a pointer you really should not cast it to any integer type. There's [an `operator<<` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that accepts `void*` and can be used for any pointers. This is especially true since the size of pointers doesn't have to be 64 bits (though on most current 64-bit systems it just happens to be). If you *really* need a pointer-sized integer, use `intptr_t` (or `uintptr_t`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Actually, I just want to cast pointers to decimal from hexadecimal, I thought it became more readable (maybe I was wrong).

Comment: Fun fact: `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<doc_ptr>());` also sorts by pointer. So this has something to do with indirection through `std::less`. But I'm not sure why. My guess would be, this particular implementation (improperly, I believe) provides a specialization of `std::less` for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right. gcc provides specialization of `std::less` for `shared_ptr`, but clang doesn't. So, we can have very simple example now: https://ideone.com/wm1YBw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that gcc provides specialization of `std::less` for `std::shared_ptr` which should't be provided. You can find all additional details in [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86537) bug report.

If I understand correctly: some early draft of C++ standard has explicitly mention, that specialization of `std::less` for `std::shared_ptr` should be provided. This mention was deleted from standard in the process of work, but wasn't deleted in the gcc code itself.

So, be careful if you are using gcc version without fix.